# Accessing application lotus scripts based using Interop.Domino

Tags: c#, interop-domino

We have a requirement to access an application built on Lotus Notes script. We need to automate / use this application from outside. This application can be accessed using Lotus Notes client.

Is it possible to access this application using Interop.Domino or is there any other way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you mean by "automate / use".

Interop.Domino is an interface to the Domino COM classes: Lotus.NotesSession, Lotus.NotesDatabase, Lotus.NotesDocument etc.  These classes can access the data that is stored by your application.  I.e., they can read, write and delete the documents stored in the application's database (NSF file).

What Interop.Domino cannot do is automate the application, by which I mean that it cannot drive the application's user interface, display views and forms, enter data into visible fields, click buttons, etc.  If that is what you want to do, then you need to use the Lotus Notes OLE classes: Notes.NotesUIWorkspace, Notes.NotesUIDatabase, Notes.NotesUIDocument, etc.

BTW: The answer to your question might also depend on what you mean by "from outside".  One important thing to know about both the Interop and OLE classes is that they require an installed Lotus Notes client or Lotus Domino server on the machine they are running on.  So if "from outside" means that you want to access the application from a machine that does not have a Notes client installed, then what you're probably going to have to do is install your code on a Domino server and provide a mechanism (e.g., a web interface) for your users to interact with it.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. By use /automate, I do not mean the UI components. Here is what I want to do.

Application A for eg. based on Lotus script has multiple documents etc and a separate UI. Here I do not want to automate UI components of Application A, but I need to access database and the documents that application A is using, using Interop.Domino. I am not sure whether this is possible.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You will need to install a Notes client on your machine in order to have the Notes core API DLLs available.  The Interop classes will then give you access to every database that you are able to access with the Notes client, including the database for "Application A".

Comment: Thanks Richard. Any quick reference on API available with you. I am trying to find out but no luck yet.

Comment: The API is fully documented in the help files that come with Domino Designer.  You really should not attempt any Domino-related development without installing it.  You can find the most recent Domino Designer client download here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/documentation/dominodesigner/  You will also find the 8.5.1 version of the help file as a separate download, which is the last version released in NSF format.  (They are now using a web-only format.)